# Windows 8.1 freezes irregularly at system reboot, cold reboot fixes it

Tags: windows, windows-8, graphics-card, freeze, reboot

My system is windows 8.1. From sometime ago, it starts to freeze irregularly at start-up during reboot. Screen shows 2 spinning dots and freezes at the windows logo screen. Turn off the PC and turn on could fix the problem in 80% chance.

I replaced memory but it doesn't fix the problem.

**UPDATE:**

I have 2 physical disks. One installs Win 8 32 bit, and one installs Win 8 64 bit. Both have same problem. Also, I try to boot from USB which has win 8 install file, it also freezes at 2 dots. It means unlikely disk error. Could it be power or motherboard problem?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling windows?

Comment: Skip trying to reinstall Windows, it won't solve this problem, replace your HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you pretty sure it is HDD issue? Do you think there is a bad spot in HDD so system freezes at exactly same bit in reboot? But it occurs only about 20% of time.

Comment: Its not a memory problem, its not likely software if it boots 80% of the time, that only leaves hardware.  The only hardware that would prevent your system from booting is your HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound I have 2 physical HDDs. One used as boot disk and the other contains Windows system folder. My understanding is that, because freeze happens at logo screen, it has past boot stage so the Windows system disk is the HDD with problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My last answer is not the actual cause. Now I finally find the root cause, which is my PSU. After I replaced it with brand new one, my PC is now running very well.

Comment: If that's the case why don't you delete it?